# Bluetooth Low Energy Weight Measurement Characteristic Timestamps

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit

I'm buffering data when my device is not connected so I need to implement timestamps so I can tell what was measured when.

fortunately the weight measurement characteristic includes a timestamp.

unfortunately it's not clear how to write this data to the package since it's not a normal data type, and it's surely not just a single byte.

https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement.xml

I'm using Adafruit's bluefruit arduino library, so I've tried just ignoring the schema and writing a unix timestamp after the SI weight but unsurprisingly it seems like the schema is not allowing that so I'm not seeing the timestamp when I receive the notifications (but i'm still seeing the correct weight readings)

Here's the link for the date_time characteristic, which is apparently the format it expects
https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.date_time.xml

I tried looking a bit in the nRF52 SDK so see if this is perhaps handled better through their API but the learning curve is a bit steep and I just need to finish this last bit to make my device work.

Update:

For anyone else with this issue the solution turned out to be that I was using the notify method the same way as it's written in the adafruit example

`wmc.notify(notification, sizeof(notification))`

because I was indexing through an N x 7 array of buffered data however `notification` is a pointer to the first element in the 1 x 7 array i was going to feed, so sizeof was always returning 4 (the size of the address I assume)  instead of the length of the array originally written which was 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [weight_scale](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.weight_scale.xml) service has two manadatory characteristics:

```
<Characteristic type="org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_scale_feature" name="Weight Scale Feature">
  <Requirement>Mandatory</Requirement>
<Characteristic type="org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement" name="Weight Measurement">
  <Requirement>Mandatory</Requirement>
```

In the [weight_measurement](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement.xml) characteristic (uuid="2A9D"), the first byte is flags. Where `<Bit index="1" size="1" name="Time stamp present">` needs to be `1` to say there will be a "Time Stamp" field. That "Time Stamp" field will be:

```
<Field name="Year"> <Format>uint16</Format> = 2 bytes
<Field name="Month"> <Format>uint8</Format> = 1 byte
<Field name="Day"> <Format>uint8</Format> = 1 byte
<Field name="Hours"> <Format>uint8</Format> = 1 byte
<Field name="Minutes"> <Format>uint8</Format> = 1 byte
<Field name="Seconds"> <Format>uint8</Format> = 1 byte
```

This makes the "Time Stamp" field 7 bytes wide.

To give a worked example of how to create the full packet if you wanted weight (in Kg) and a time stamp it will need to 10 bytes long:

```
<Field name="Flags"> <Format>8bit</Format>  = 1 byte
<Field name="Weight - SI "> <Format>uint16</Format> = 2 bytes
<Field name="Time Stamp"> = 7 bytes
```

I've used Python to calculate the value of a packet:

```py
import struct

flags = 0b00000010 # Include time. SI units
weight_raw = 38.1 #  Weight of 38.1 Kg
weight = int((weight_raw/5)*1000) # Formula from XML
year = 1972
month = 12
day = 11
hour = 23
minute = 22
second = 8

packet = struct.pack('<BHHBBBBB', flags, weight, year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
print(packet)
```

Which would give a packet of 10 bytes long:

```
b'\x02\xc4\x1d\xb4\x07\x0c\x0b\x17\x16\x08'
```

Comment: Here's how i'm building the package to send:
`(uint8_t package[packageSize]  = {0b00000010,highByte(weight),lowByte(weight),0,0,highByte(yr),lowByte(yr),now.month(),now.day(),now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second()};)`


what i'm sending::  294A007E49615C18
what i'm receiving: 294A09E670AAE775C5

Comment: Your packet looks the wrong length. You are putting `0,0` in the packet which is not necessary. I've updated my answer with what a packet should look like. Maybe update your question with more details of how you are creating the packet as the formatting is getting mangled in the comments